# Cannot change the content of visited :before pseudo-elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

I was trying to add some effects for visited links, then I got this problem.

Here is the code: http://dabblet.com/gist/5447894

Only Opera can successfully change the content of `:before` pseudo-elements. All other browsers are fail. Did I miss anything? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox 4 not rendering a:visited::before (except color)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839127/firefox-4-not-rendering-avisitedbefore-except-color)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The allowed (= not ignored) CSS properties of visited links are `color`, `background-color`, `border-*-color`, `outline-color` and, `column-rule-color` (more under certain circumstances).

This is to prevent history stealing attacks. See [this article](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy#limits) for further details.

So you can, technically, set a `:before` pseudo class for `:visited` links, but it will be ignored and appears as if the links are not visited. This is not a bug, it's a feature ;)

Comment: It means opera has lack of security!

Answer (score 3):

There is a very limited range of possibilities for styling `:visited` links in modern browsers for privacy reasons – so that you couldn't detect which sites the user has visited before by checking the computed style with javascript.

The allowed properties for styling for `:visited` links is

- `color`
- `background-color`
- `border-color` (and its sub-properties)
- `outline-color`
- The color parts of the fill and stroke properties

Even so, you cannot get the values of the computed style for visited links via javascript.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector).