# Using a font-face embedded font as hyperlink does not work

Tags: css, hyperlink, font-face

Using the Liberation font on a website works fine for standard text. However I also want to use that font as my text linked font but using the following code it does not call/use the font.

```
a:link {
color: #69f;
font-family: liberation_sansbold;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bolder;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none

}
```

This is the embedded font on my website (and as I said it works fine for regualr (non-linked) text).

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'liberation_sansbold';
src: url('website.com/liberationsans-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('website.com/liberationsans-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix')     format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('website.com/liberationsans-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('website.com/liberationsans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('website.com/liberationsans-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('website.com/liberationsans-bold-webfont.svg#liberation_sansbold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30859682/72625) -- most browsers appear to limit what styles you can apply to some pseudo classes. The answer I linked to applies to `:visited`, but I wouldn't be surprised if similar limitations applied to `:link`. Try just styling `a`, not `a:link` -- I'm guessing you probably want your font to be used for all types of links anyway.