# How can I set different icons for visited and unvisited external links with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to set different icons for visited and unvisited external links. At first, I tried this:

```
a[href^="http"] {
    padding-right: 1.1em;
    background-image: url(external_link.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
a[href^="http"]:visited {
    background-image: url(visited_external_link.gif);
}
```

— but, obviously, it didn't work.

This:

```
a {
    padding-right: 1.1em;
    background-image: url(external_link.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
a:visited {
    background-image: url(visited_external_link.gif);
}
a:not([href^="http"]) {
    background-image: none;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

— didn't work too.

So, how can I to set different icons or, in other words, change icon only for visited external links? Is it possible without classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine a:visited with a:after, or chaining pseudo-classes with pseudo-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342516/combine-avisited-with-aafter-or-chaining-pseudo-classes-with-pseudo-elements)

Comment: It's another question, combining and chaining pseudo-* doesn't help in this case, question focused on **external** links (`[href^="http"]`). But thanks.

Comment: Just a note: it's ::after and ::before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In theory* you could try using the `a:visited:before` or the `:after` selector in combination with an icon font like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/), which would look something like:

```
a:visited:before {
   content: "\icon-code";
}
```

Or you could use your background-image:

```
a:visited:before {
   content: " ";
   background-image: url('your-background-image.jpg');
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
}
```

However, **beware** that the `:visited` selectors have restrictions regarding psuedo-elements in modern browsers ([to protect your privacy](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)); for example in Firefox 4 you are only allowed to change an `a:visited` links' (border) colors (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342516/combine-avisited-with-aafter-or-chaining-pseudo-classes-with-pseudo-elements) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839127/firefox-4-not-rendering-avisitedbefore-except-color) for reference).

Thus, as mentioned by other answers, **the above will not work in production because popular browsers will not render it** ([per W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)).

Direct quote from the Mozilla Developer Network on the issue:

> Note: For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke. Note also that the alpha component will be ignored: the alpha component of the not-visited rule is used instead (except when the opacity is 0, in that case the whole color is ignored, and the one of the not-visited rule is used).

And you'd say that's the end of that, **but it's not**!
There ([1](https://una.im/hacking-visited/)) are ([2](http://stelian.firez.be/post/pushing-the-limits-of-visited-with-css-blend-modes/)) a lot ([3](http://joelcalifa.com/blog/revisiting-visited/)) of interesting ways to circumvent these restrictions (for a detailed blog post with a lot of references to this issue, you can look [here on CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/)).

For example, one of the tricks is to style two `a` elements that link to the same `href`, and style the first one to be an icon. When someone clicks on the link with text, the `a` in front [also gets affected](https://www.quora.com/How-does-DuckDuckGos-new-visited-feature-work).

Here's an example from the previously linked [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-DuckDuckGos-new-visited-feature-work) post (which is based on the DuckDuckGo's visited feature) (which sadly won't work as a working snippit due to it working with links):

```
<h2 class="result__title">
   <a class="result__a" href="https://google.com">Link to Google
   </a>
   <a class="result__check" href="https://google.com">
       <span class="result__check__tt">Link icon</span>
   </a>
</h2>
```

Now in your CSS you make the `.result__check` only show up (in your stylesheet) if you've visited the link!

```
.result__check:before{
    content: "\2611";
}
.result__check {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0.3em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.result__check:before{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
// This is what gives the color to the visited item
.result__check:visited {
    color: #c3c3c3;
}
.result__check__tt {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #a3a3a3;
    background-color: rgba(138,138,138,0.9);
    padding: 0 1em;
    font-size: 0.76em;
    line-height: 2;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2.5em;
    left: -0.95em;
    z-index: 200
}
.result__check__tt:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    bottom: -0.5em;
    left: 1.5em;
    border: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-top-color: #a3a3a3;
    border-top-color: rgba(138,138,138,0.9)
}
.result__check:hover .result__check__tt {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1
}
```

That way, you *are* able to style the `:visited` element, even though browsers restrict it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo element suggestions in other answers or other approaches (short of perhaps JavaScript) will not work.  Per W3 schools https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp:

> Browsers limits the styles that can be set for a:visited links, due to security issues.
>
> Allowed styles are:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - border-color (and border-color for separate sides)
> - outline color
> - column-rule-color
> - the color parts of fill and stroke
>
> All other styles are inherited from a:link.

Even using pseudo elements as others have recommended do not work since you still need to include `:visited` in the css declaration, which continues to prevent you from adding background images.