# Change color of an icon on a site, when that icon's underlying link becomes :visited

Tags: css, visited

There are many identical icons on a site, each with a different underlying link.
To change stuff I use Stylish app in the Chrome browser.
In Stylish I have

```
a:visited {color:grey;}
```

which works great on normal (alphanumeric) links, but it doesn’t change the color of visited icons (why oh why?!). I have determined the class that controls the color of the icons:

```
[data-ma-theme=blue-grey] .playlist__actions:not(.track_page) a
```

But no matter what I tried to do with the combination of this class and `:visited`, I failed. I put `:visited` before and after the class name, added and removed “a”, unticked other items in DevTools’ Styles pane that I thought might override my setting, it just won’t work.

At the same time it changes color just fine when I add  `:hover`, so why wouldn’t it work with `:visited`??

If this of any help, in Chrome’s DevTools in the Elements pane this is what I have for the icon in question and its underlying link:

```
<a target=”…” itemprop=”…” href=”…” class=” ___adv-binded ___adv-sape …” id=”…” title=”…”>
== $0
<span>
<i class=”zdmi…” style>…</i>
```

I tried using  `.___adv-binded` and `.zdmi` classes with `:visited`, but it doesn’t work either.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099903/how-can-i-set-different-icons-for-visited-and-unvisited-external-links-with-css

Comment: I am not sure how it applies to my case. There they discuss how to apply styles that are not allowed by browsers for :visited items. In my case, on the other hand, I just need to change the color, which is perfectly allowed by browsers. I tried using a:visited:before and :after, but it didn't work.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I misunderstood your question. The approach detailed in the first answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099903/how-can-i-set-different-icons-for-visited-and-unvisited-external-links-with-css)  suggests using an icon font like fontawesome, and placing the icon character inside an <a> with an identical href. That way the icon should correctly gain the ":visited" pseudoclass. If that approach is not working for you, please post more of your code (relevant css and html around the icon).

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is not working because of you do not have href link. If there is no href link this mean you did not visited before.

```
<nav>
<li><a href="https://www.google.co.in/">Visit Link</a> </li>
</nav>
```

please try with link, good luck.

Comment: They obviously have an href link, they've just substituted their attribute values with `...` as they are not relevant to the question. Were they relevant OP would have added the `HTML` tag to the question.

Comment: href does have a link in the Elements pane of DevTools window, I referred to it as href=”…” . Or do you mean something else?